# How to run a method only after a frame has been closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So, my code right now looks like this:

```
Class2 className = new Class2(param1, param2);
className = null;
if (Class2 == null) {
    refreshState();
}
```

I want the `refreshState` method to run once the `className` object is destroyed. So basically `Class2` is a class that runs another frame on top of my existing frame. I want the method to run only when the new frame has been closed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So basically Class2 is a class that runs another frame on top of my existing frame. I want the method to run only when the new frame has been closed. How can I do this?

The better solution is to use modal dialogs such as a JOptionPane or a modal JDialog. This will stop the processing of the Swing code in the main window until the dialog window has been dealt with and is no longer visible. Then your refreshState can run immediately after the dialog has been closed:

Pseudocode:

```
main window code
show modal dialog
refresh state here. This will be called only after the dialog has returned.
```

Comment: Well, that could work, but the problem is that `Class2` in itself is a complete program! It's work cannot be substituted by a JDialog.

Comment: @user2059238: My answer is still correct and your problem is that your dependent window class was created incorrectly. You should never create a class that extends a JFrame just so you can avoid this very problem. Create JPanels, and then you can put them in dialogs or JFrames or whatever is needed at the time. You will need to re-write that code.

Comment: @user2059238: it is a bit of work but it is far better, easier and will take shorter time in the long run than trying to create a kludge to get around a bad design which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: The other way around this is to add a WindowListener to the dependent Window and acting once it notifies you that the window has been closed, but again my original suggestion is more what you need to do.

Comment: I tried to add a Dialog, but having a hard time migrating my frame to a dialog. Since my Frame is a complete program in itself, it's really challenging to convert it into a dialog. I've gone through tons of docs and SO threads, but nothing really helped! :/

Comment: @user2059238: well, I wish you the best of luck! Keep on plugging!

Comment: Hmm.. I ended up using a WindowListener for now. :)

Comment: @user2059238: OK. One other trick to consider is to create your JFrame, get its contantPane via `getContentPane()`, and shove that contentPane into a JDialog created at that time using `setContentPane(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say add a java.awt.event.WindowListener to the frame:

```
class2.getFrame().addWindowsListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent we) {
        // The frame is closed, let's dot something else
        refreshState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but this code doesn;t work for me. I imprement the `getFrame()` but get `The method addWindowsListener(new WindowAdapter(){}) is undefined for the type JFrame`